# An iterator returning all possible partitions of a list in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, combinatorics, iteration

Given a list of \$n\$ objects and an integer \$k \in \{ 1, 2, \dots, n \}\$, this iterator generates all possible ways of partitioning the elements in the list into exactly \$k\$ disjoint, non-empty blocks (*partitions*).

There is exactly \$S(n, k)\$ such partitions,  see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind.

My code is as follows:

**`PartitionIterable.java:`**

```
package net.coderodde.util;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

/**
 * This class implements an {@code Iterable} over all partitions of a given 
 * list.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Feb 14, 2016 a.k.a. Friend Edition)
 * @param <T> The actual element type.
 */
public class PartitionIterable<T> implements Iterable<List<List<T>>> {

    private final List<T> allElements = new ArrayList<>();
    private final int blocks;

    public PartitionIterable(List<T> allElements, int blocks) {
        checkNumberOfBlocks(blocks, allElements.size());
        this.allElements.addAll(allElements);
        this.blocks = blocks;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<List<List<T>>> iterator() {
        return new PartitionIterator<>(allElements, blocks);
    }

    private void checkNumberOfBlocks(int blocks, int numberOfElements) {
        if (blocks < 1) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "The number of blocks should be at least 1, received: " +
                    blocks);
        }

        if (blocks > numberOfElements) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "The number of blocks should be at most " +
                    numberOfElements + ", received: " + blocks);
        }   
    }

    private static final class PartitionIterator<T> 
    implements Iterator<List<List<T>>> {

        private List<List<T>> nextPartition;
        private final List<T> allElements = new ArrayList<>();
        private final int blocks;

        private final int[] s;
        private final int[] m;
        private final int n;

        PartitionIterator(List<T> allElements, int blocks) {
            this.allElements.addAll(allElements);
            this.blocks = blocks;
            this.n = allElements.size();

            s = new int[n];
            m = new int[n];

            if (n != 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < n - blocks + 1; ++i) {
                    s[i] = 0;
                    m[i] = 0;
                }

                for (int i = n - blocks + 1; i < n; ++i) {
                    s[i] = m[i] = i - n + blocks;
                }

                loadPartition();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return nextPartition != null;
        }

        @Override
        public List<List<T>> next() {
            if (nextPartition == null) {
                throw new NoSuchElementException("No more partitions left.");
            }

            List<List<T>> partition = nextPartition;
            generateNextPartition();
            return partition;
        }

        private void loadPartition() {
            nextPartition = new ArrayList<>(blocks);

            for (int i = 0; i < blocks; ++i) {
                nextPartition.add(new ArrayList<>());
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
                nextPartition.get(s[i]).add(allElements.get(i));
            }
        }

        private void generateNextPartition() {
            for (int i = n - 1; i > 0; --i) {
                if (s[i] < blocks - 1 && s[i] <= m[i - 1]) {
                    s[i]++;
                    m[i] = Math.max(m[i], s[i]);

                    for (int j = i + 1; j < n - blocks + m[i] + 1; ++j) {
                        s[j] = 0;
                        m[j] = m[i];
                    }

                    for (int j = n - blocks + m[i] + 1; j < n; ++j) {
                        s[j] = m[j] = blocks - n + j;
                    }

                    loadPartition();
                    return;
                }
            }

            nextPartition = null;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C", "D");
        int row = 1;

        for (int blocks = 1; blocks <= list.size(); ++blocks) {
            for (List<List<String>> partition : 
                    new PartitionIterable<>(list, blocks)) {
                System.out.printf("%2d: %s\n", row++, partition);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For example, all partitions of the set \$\{ A, B, C, D \}\$ are

```
 1: [[A, B, C, D]]
 2: [[A, B, C], [D]]
 3: [[A, B, D], [C]]
 4: [[A, B], [C, D]]
 5: [[A, C, D], [B]]
 6: [[A, C], [B, D]]
 7: [[A, D], [B, C]]
 8: [[A], [B, C, D]]
 9: [[A, B], [C], [D]]
10: [[A, C], [B], [D]]
11: [[A], [B, C], [D]]
12: [[A, D], [B], [C]]
13: [[A], [B, D], [C]]
14: [[A], [B], [C, D]]
15: [[A], [B], [C], [D]]
```

Is there anything to improve here?

Comment: (That's a bold result.) Does `Friend Edition` mean you are working on a C++ rendition in parallel?

Comment: No, I don't as I ain't proficient in C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You code looks really good but there are always ways for improvement :)

1. Add to `main` method printout of current \$k\$. For me output was unclear without it and I couldn't compare the output with "golden" [table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind#Table_of_values).
2. I would rename `allElements` to `elements` cause `all-` doesn't give any additional information.
3. Strings in `IllegalArgumentException` constructors may be changed to `String.format("...text...", params...)` it'll simplify [i18n](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalization_and_localization) of such strings in the future
4. Use `java.util.Arrays#fill` for arrays filling instead of circles or even remove zeroing at all as Java Spec [guarantees](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5) arrays zeroing after initialization.
5. Extract this initialization into a separate method (remember of [SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle))
6. Make parameters' checks in `checkNumberOfBlocks` and `PartitionIterator` consistent (or even remove it from `PartitionIterator` at all as it's `private` impl)
7. Split `generateNextPartition` into some separate methods with SRP and appropriate names. E.g. for me is unclear how `generateNextPartition` works now. Remember empty lines in a method code is the sign of breaking SRP and is like ["code smell"](http://www.yegor256.com/2014/11/03/empty-line-code-smell.html) in the most cases

Answer (score 1):

Looks good.  For debugging and understanding I'd also print the block
size in the test loop, that makes checking the results a bit more
straightforward.

The initialisation of `allElements` / lists in general could be fully
done in the constructor instead of splitting it up, i.e.:

```
    this.allElements = new ArrayList<>(allElements);
```

Copying over all the elements seems a bit wasteful, especially since
that list is never modified.  I'd argue that since you're only allowing
`List`s to be passed in the caller should have to provide an efficient
list instead of you copying a lot internally.  Same goes for
modification:  You're not going to modify the incoming list, so assume
that the list is not changing underneath you and let the caller copy if
necessary.

The same argument could be made for the generated partitions, but then
again, the hassle of reusing elements is possibly not worth it for
clarity.  That said, the process of `generateNextPartition` *and*
`loadPartition` looks a bit weird since it could very well be done in
one step?

Removing the `n != 0` condition in the `PartitionIterator` constructor
doesn't change the behaviour, because the `blocks` argument is already
checked outside of the iterator class.

Also initialising to zero doesn't do much there as both arrays are
allocated right before that and will default to zero anyway.

That also reminds me that you should post the test cases as well.  You
*do* have some, right?